# Python:update a list by adding a string to all elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2.7, Windows 10

I have a code that finds all the sheet names of an excel file then puts then splits the string and puts it in a list. The next step of my code needs to attach the file path to the sheet names in the list. The file path will be a constant variable.

I realize that this code is incorrect, but I basically just need to be able to do something like this:

```
List = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
for i in list
    print("file_Path" + i)   

'file_path test1'
'file_path test2'
```

But I need it to update the list or append to a new list instead of print. What is the best method to do this. I've looked pretty hard to find a good answer to this, but I realize I might be searching in the wrong place.

Thanks!

Comment: `List = ['file_Path ' + i for i in List]`

Comment: `newList = [ "{} {}".format(yourPath,x) for x in List]`

Comment: As a side note: if there's actually a reason you have to use Python 2.7, you should probably use the 2.x-style `print` statement, or add a `from __future__ import print_function`, instead of just pretending you're using 3.x. Otherwise, you're eventually going to end up confusing yourself by printing out things like `(1, 2)` when you wanted `1 2` and having to figure out how to debug code that looks correct at first glance.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up abarnet. The first answer from Primusa worked like a charm and I will check out the other solutions when I go to optimize my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by people in the comment section, **your best bet for this type of task is using list comprehension** like so,

```
['file_Path ' + i for i in List]
```

Now, I wanted to add an answer because I wanted to add that `List` is definitely not a good choice of naming for you `list` object.

**I would go with something more meaningful and further from the `list` keyword**

(eg. `sheet_names`)

```
sheet_names = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
sheet_names = ['file_Path ' + i for i in sheet_names]
print(sheet_names)
>>>>['file_Path test1', 'file_Path test2', 'file_Path test3']
```

Comment: I never really use List as a variable. I just use it as an example. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be the better way as i always use this

```
oldList = ['test1','test2','test3']
newList = list(map(lambda a:"file path "+a,oldList))
```

It looks functional

Comment: it looks functional, but a lot less readable than `['file_Path ' + x for x in List]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] = 'file_path ' + list[i]
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
new_list = ['file_path ' + item for item in list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to perform this task -

```
List = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
file_path = 'your/file/path'
newList = [file_path+SheetName for SheetName in List]
```

Or you could use the map+lambda combination -

```
newList = list(map(lambda x: file_path+x , List))
```

Comment: `filter` filters items, it doesn't change them. You're thinking of `list(map(lambda x: file_path+x , List))`

Comment: isn't chaining `list` and `map` redundant in py2?

Answer (score 0):

Just use list comprehension:

```
List = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
file_paths = ['file_path: %s' % (fp,) for fp in List]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the combination of `map` and `add` which adds two lists element wise.

```
from operator import add
test = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
path = ['file_Path '] * len(test)
list(map(add, path, test))
```

**Output**

```
['file_Path test1', 'file_Path test2', 'file_Path test3']
```